# Benchmark a function over different inputs (of different sizes) in python efficiently

Tags: python, testing, pytest, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark a function over different inputs which have different sizes.

For example I have a function `something(array)` that takes a numpy array with variable length as an input and a list of possible arguments `args = [np.random.rand(3, 2, i) for i in range(1,1000)]`. 
What I want to do now is to test the time `something` needs dependent on the input.

What I currently did is the following:

```
def iterator(ys):

    times = []
    for i in range(len(ys)):
        start = timer()
        test = something(ys[i])
        end = timer()
        times.append(end - start)

    return times
```

With this I get the results I want. The problem is that with this method I do not get any key figures like the variance or mean for each input size. 
I could also do a second loop where I run the `iterator` several times and use the results to compute the key figures but I'd rather use an established method if there is one.

I tried to apply `pytest-benchmark` (https://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but was not able to find a way where I could pass a list of arguments to a function.

Maybe some of you have a nice solution to this!

Comment: Check out the [perfplot](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/) package.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is to perform timing measurements using the Ipython line magic `%timeit` or cell magic `%%timeit`. I usually define input data sizes that I want to test and run it in a loop:

```py
def list_search(lst, item):
    for el in lst:
        if el == item:
            return True
    return False

for n in (100, 1000, 10000, 100000):
    data = list(range(n)) 
    %timeit list_search(data, data[-1])
```

The %timeit function takes a number of arguments to modify its behavior:

> %timeit [-n -r [-t|-c] -q -p<P> -o] statement
>
> Options: -n: execute the given statement  times in a loop. If  is not provided,  is determined so as to get sufficient accuracy.
>
> -r: number of repeats , each consisting of  loops, and take the best result. Default: 7

(From https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)